# How does JSON.parse manage 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, json

I transformed this:

```
function MangaElt(obj) {
  "use strict";
  this.mirror = obj.mirror;
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.url = obj.url;
  if (obj.lastChapterReadURL !== undefined) {
    this.lastChapterReadURL = obj.lastChapterReadURL;
    this.lastChapterReadName = obj.lastChapterReadName;
  } else {
    this.lastChapterReadURL = null;
    this.lastChapterReadName = null;
  }
  this.listChaps = [];
  if (obj.listChaps !== undefined && obj.listChaps !== null && obj.listChaps !== "null") {
    if (!isArray(obj.listChaps)) {
      this.listChaps = JSON.parse(obj.listChaps);
    }
  }
  this.read = 0;
  if (obj.read !== undefined && obj.read !== null && obj.read !== "null") {
    this.read = obj.read;
  }
}
```

Into this:

```
function MangaElt(obj) {
  "use strict";
  this.mirror = obj.mirror;
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.url = obj.url;
  this.lastChapterReadURL = obj.lastChapterReadURL || null;
  this.lastChapterReadName = obj.lastChapterReadName || null;
  this.listChaps = JSON.parse(obj.listChaps) || [];
  this.read = obj.read || 0;
  this.update = obj.update || 1;
}
```

As you can see, the code is now more readable and compact. The snippet works under normal circumstances just fine. The thing is that I don't have sometimes all the values in the `obj` object, so, I expect some `undefined`'s here and there. And that is the reason of my questions:

1. Why `JSON.parse` interpret a `undefined` as string, trowing as say the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), "syntax error" for `undefined`?
2. Should then, I, check before the values get parsed if the value is a proper string?
3. Shouldn't JSON.parse, check whenever the value parsed is `undefined` and just return `undefined`? (This may rise arguments, so, if you believe that is good as is, just ignore this question or state that I'm just wrong with my train of trough)
4. If #2 is affirmative, then just adding some conditional as the first snipped should be enough, right? Or should I go to the function that calls MangaElt and make sure that `obj.listChaps` is an array and forget about `JSON.parse` here?. ([This is always an array](http://pastebin.com/niQ6qG0P) or a pseudo-array in a string, and since this is a collaborative project, someone may have a reason for this)

For the curious that may ask, 'what's the error you are getting?' is this:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Unexpected token u SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)
at new MangaElt (chrome-extension://nhjloagockgobfpopemejpgjjechcpfd/js/MangaElt.js:44:25)
at readManga (chrome-extension://nhjloagockgobfpopemejpgjjechcpfd/js/background.js:410:24)
at chrome-extension://nhjloagockgobfpopemejpgjjechcpfd/js/background.js:607:9
at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
at miscellaneous_bindings:165:24
at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27) event_bindings:346
```

[This is what already existing entries looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p52OB.png), which do not generate errors. [This scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pahVw.png) is what motivated my question. The type of keys are always the same and are tested beforehand:

- `name` is a string
- `mirror` is a string
- `url` is a string
- `listChaps` is an "array" inside a string
- `ts` and `upts` are integers

BTW, `obj` is an object, but I think that it's almost impossible to miss. Also, this is a Chrome extension, but I don't think that's relevant. Complete script [here](https://github.com/AllMangasReader-dev/AMR/blob/develop/js/MangaElt.js).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`undefined` is not a valid JSON token. When converting an undefined value to JSON, the correct practice is to render it as null.

Comment: Strangely enough it tries to parse `undefined` as string in Google Chrome/ium. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Braiam: `JSON.parse` interprets *anything* you send to it as a string. It does the equivalent of `String(input)`, meaning literal `true`, `false`, `25`, `null` will be accepted. `undefined` won't, because that isn't valid JSON per section 15.12.1.2 in the spec you posted in the other comment.

Answer (score 12):

1. `undefined` is not a legal token in a JSON file (see www.json.org) nor is it an acceptable parameter to `JSON.parse`
2. Your code is not semantically identical to the previous version.  Many of the tests in the previous version are more exhaustive (and less error prone) than your new version
3. Why "refactor" that code if worked as desired?  You have not refactored it - you've *broken* it.

Comment: 1. I checked out the site, no reference about how to handle `undefined` were made there nor in the [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) 3. I used breakpoints for almost an hour before doing changes and never got `undefined` or `null` (except for the JSON part). That's why I considered the extra lines unnecessary. So, care to elaborate how, if both has the same behavior, I've broken it? 2. As #3, the implicit testing was not necessary, so I used cheaper methods.

Comment: Alnitak's point is that `undefined` is not a legal token, which is exactly *why* there's no reference about how to handle it. It's not valid, so it's handled like any other invalid input.

Comment: If you really need it in your response json code, it should be given as a string.