# JSON.parse string with undefined

Tags: node.js, json, kafka-consumer-api

In my NodeJS app I receive messages from kafka, messages arrived as buffer so I do:

```
let myMsg = kafkaMessage.message.value.toString();
```

`myMsg` is now `String`, I have problem with the following string:

```
"{
  "Data": {
    "a": undefined,
    "b": undefined,
    "c": {
      "d": undefined,
      "e": undefined,
      "f": [
        0,
        0,
        0
      ]
    },
  },
  "g": {
    "h": 598972702657,
    "i": "abcd",
  },
  "time": "2018-12-24T13:18:22.6577119"
}"
```

It fails when I try to do `JSON.parse(myMsg)` because some values are undefined.
The messages without undefined are passed succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the JSON.parse() method fails is explained here : [How does JSON.parse manage 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648150/how-does-json-parse-manage-undefined)

One possible workaround is to replace all the 'undefined' substrings with 'null' in the myMsg string before calling the JSON.parse() method on it.

Comment: Can you also share `kafkaMessage.message.value` without turning it into a string?

Comment: its buffer, what else can you do?